# Is there a way to select multiple sprites from a sprite sheet in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, transparency, background, sprite

After you've made the background transparent, color selected the background and inverted the selection to outline all the character sprites:

Is there a shortcut or some quicker method/program/tool to turn each sprite into an individual selection and then turn each selection into an individual layer? If not with GIMP, are there any other free programs that will allow you to do this?

Comment: Be more specific, please. Is there a sort of regularity for your sprites (e.g. equidistant spacing or similar)? If yes, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to [split the image into tiles](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10027).

Comment: See also [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42039/exporting-square-tiles-from-a-stripe-in-inkscape-or-gimp#comment59123_42039)

Comment: Are you trying to get all of your sprites as layers? For example, you start with a 100x100 image with 25 sprites that are 20x20, and you want to end up with a 20x20 image with 25 layers, one sprite per layer. I'm curious what the usefulness of that would be, but if that's what you want to do, splitting to image into individual files per sprite, then importing as layers is probably the fastest.