# Exporting square tiles from a stripe - in Inkscape or Gimp

Tags: gimp, inkscape, export, tiles

I am using Inkscape and Gimp to create assets for a word game and am looking for an advice from more experienced users of these great tools.

In Inkscape I have created [a stripe](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q6/MyStripe/english.svg) with 26 letters and their values:

[image: Inkscape stripe]

The stripe is comfortable to edit - I have enabled grid snapping there and also I can always revisit the SVG file and change font sizes or letter values.

Then I have exported the SVG file as a whole page to PNG files in different resolutions:

[image: Inkscape bitmap]

Unfortunately, loading [a 6240 x 240 pixels PNG file](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q6/MyStripe/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png) does not work with Android (because of OpenGL width limitation for textures - 2048 pixels on many devices).

So I have to split the SVG file or the resulting PNG files in square images of 240 x 240 pixels for each letter (Android could process them without problems).

**My question is** if anyone knows a good way to perform such a split in Inkscape (that would be best) or in Gimp?

In *Export Bitmap* dialog of Inkscape I see a batch-related checkbox... Could it be used for my purposes?

Comment: opengl prefers square layouts so you can make a 2048 by 2048 picture you have no problem fitting it there and it should be easy and quick to do manually

Comment: Unfortunately that [does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871205/loading-26-letter-images-from-a-png-stripe-using-bitmapregiondecoder) on my Android devices.

Comment: sure it does, the system is even saying so. Theres no reason for all that data be in one row.

Comment: How is this problem different from [this one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41944/19174) and if so, what is your problem with the solution there (that you accepted)?

Comment: First question was about creating a stripe of similar elements in Inkscape (I was hoping for a way to change positions and font sizes at once). The second question is about batch-exporting quadratic areas of Inkscape or Gimp document.

Comment: The answer of @Drasil is correct, have you tried to apply it? P.S. [quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic) is a term more related to functions, are you meaning [square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square)?

Comment: Yes, **square**, thank you. I'm sure ImageMagick will work (+1 his answer), but am still looking for a way in Inkscape/Gimp...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in **Gimp**, but in my opinion is simpler with **ImageMagick** (see also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/20081/can-the-gimp-split-an-image-into-multiple-images)).

You need to put a lot of [guidelines](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/C/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html) where you need to cut:

[image: guidelines]

And then simply apply the [Guillotine](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/C/plug-in-guillotine.html) transform:

[image: guillotine]

After this, you have the original image split in a lot of *imagettes*:

[image: a lot of images]

And you have to save - pardon, export - each of them with a proper name.

Ok, maybe you can use a [script](https://github.com/pft/script-fu/blob/master/script-fu-add-guides.scm) for the guidelines and apply the [slice](http://docs.gimp.org/en/python-fu-slice.html) plugin (which saves the pictures in a folder) to make it faster...

In **Inkscape** you can choose the area to export, and you can simply calculate the proper coordinates and save each image:

[image: save area in Inkscape]

See also [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=12114) for Inkscape.

Trust me, I love Gimp and Inkscape, but a more proper tool for *this* kind of operation is [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) ;-).

Comment: +1 thanks for the great answer. However I've tried exporting bitmap in Inkscape as a 240 x 240 area - it is nearly impossible (always resets and exports wrong area), at least on Mac. I will try Windows soon.

Comment: Ok, let us known if you did it!

Answer (score 2):

I would use another tool, like "image magick", to "compile" your exported png into slices.

For example : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

Comment: Answer is correct, but imho you can improve it with an example of the usage of convert, e.g. *convert.exe big_english.png -crop 240x240 letter_%d.png* (which should work), and showing one of the obtained images.